# Compare variables in two frame in R with loop

Tags: r, loops

I am trying to compare the matches across two datasets with the same variables, variable-by-variable. Using a loop, I can't quite get the names of the variable vector to go work. Here is an example of the code:

```
vars <- c("a", "b", "c")
x <- data.frame(a = rnorm(100), b = rnorm(100), c=rnorm(100))
y <- data.frame(a = rnorm(100), b = rnorm(100), c=rnorm(100))

for(i in 1:length(vars)){
    print(table(x$vars[i] %in% y$vars[i]))
}
```

Any and all thoughts greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't access the column of a `data.frame` with `$` and a variable name. In your example you look for the `i`th element of the column `vars` (that not exists) in `data.frame` `x` and `y`. The correct way of accessing would be `[`:

```
for(i in 1:length(vars)){
    print(table(x[, vars[i]] %in% y[, vars[i]]))
}
```

BTW: you could use `mapply` for that purposes and avoiding accessing columns manually:

```
mapply(function(xx, yy)table(xx %in% yy), xx=x, yy=y)
```